# copy a row of varied length, transpose it, and paste at the end of a column

Tags: vba, excel, transpose

I am working on a macro to copy a varied number of cells to a row, transpose and paste into a different sheet, in the next empty cell in a column. Then the idea is to match each transposed item with the ID from the row it originated from.  The number of rows in the ID column will vary as well.

Looking at the example below, ID 1 is associated with Co D and Co R. Transposing would create the need for ID 1 to be copied into the two cells adjacent to the destination. This example I created has them on the same sheet, but for the code itself it will be on a different sheet.

[image]

The problem appears in copying the range to be transposed.  I can't seem to figure out how to grab the whole row.  The macro correctly pastes the value in the next available cell in the destination, but the version of the code I have now only copies the last result in the row, and not the whole row which is my intent.  I haven't even gotten to the part of matching the ID to the Co in the Destination column, but I am dreading it already.  The code I have is as follows;

```
Sub Testing()

Dim TearS As Worksheet:         Set TearS = Worksheets(1)
Dim FeeS As Worksheet:          Set FeeS = Worksheets(2)
Dim EntryS As Worksheet:        Set EntryS = Worksheets(3)
Dim Stage2 As Worksheet:        Set Stage2 = Worksheets(4)
Dim Stage3 As Worksheet:        Set Stage3 = Worksheets(5)

Dim Bbg As Range:               Set Bbg = EntryS.Range("F4:T199")
Dim TDest As Range:             Set TDest = Stage2.Range("F5:T200")
Dim DateA As Range:         Set DateA = Stage2.Range("G5:G200")
Dim DateB As Range:         Set DateB = TearS.Range("E5:E200")
Dim DesA As Range:          Set DesA = Stage2.Range("J5:J200")
Dim DesB As Range:          Set DesB = TearS.Range("O5:O200")
Dim DesC As Range:          Set DesC = Stage3.Range("C5:C200")
Dim CpnMatA As Range:       Set CpnMatA = Stage2.Range("Y5:Y200")
Dim CpnMatB As Range:       Set CpnMatB = TearS.Range("P5:P500")
Dim SettA As Range:         Set SettA = Stage2.Range("I5:I200")
Dim SettB As Range:         Set SettB = TearS.Range("Q5:Q200")
Dim MinA As Range:          Set MinA = Stage2.Range("AA5:AA200")
Dim MinB As Range:          Set MinB = Stage3.Range("D5:D200")
Dim MWOB As Range:          Set MWOB = TearS.Range("N5:N200")

Dim Cel As Range

For Each Cel In DesC
    If IsEmpty(Cel) = False Then
        Cel.Offset(0, 1).End(xlToRight).Copy
            TearS.Range("N3").End(xlDown).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

    End If
Next Cel

End Sub
```

Edit: Jeeped's solution that you can see in the answer below works swimmingly.  Make sure that there are no errors in the source data, or you may get a run-time error 13.

Comment: a) Please do not request recommendations or links to outside learning resources. This is **specifically** a reason to close a question. b) While personal taste may be a factor, I find msdn.microsoft.com to be a very valuable resource. You can also look at [SO VBA documentation site](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba).

Comment: I see you got tired of typing in the sample data and started copying rows 5-9 from row 4. What makes you think I want to retype your data before proofing a proposed answer?

Comment: If you have Excel 2010 or later, you can just use `Power Query` or `Data --> Get & Transform` and unpivot the columns other than column 1.  If you need a macro, record one while you are doing that.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Apologies on rows 5 through 9, but they just happened to have the same companies associated with them.  But, now that you mention it, I can certainly see that it looks lazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try transposing within a 2-D array before passing the values back to the worksheet.

```
Sub rewrite()
    Dim lr As Long, a As Long, b As Long, val As Variant, vals As Variant

    With Worksheets("sheet6")
        .Range("F:G").Clear
        lr = Application.Max(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row, _
                             .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row, _
                             .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row, _
                             .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)
        vals = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(lr, "E")).Value2
        For a = LBound(vals, 1) To UBound(vals, 1)
            ReDim val(1 To UBound(vals, 2), 1 To 2)
            For b = LBound(val, 1) To UBound(val, 1) - 1
                If CBool(Len(vals(a, b + 1))) Then
                    val(b, 1) = vals(a, 1)
                    val(b, 2) = vals(a, b + 1)
                End If
            Next b
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(val, 1), UBound(val, 2)) = val
        Next a
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You might also try to *unpivot* your data.

Comment: Thank you for the code.  When I copied it into the sheet to test it, it worked great. After some modifications to the code, renaming the sheet and adding a few columns as the number of companies can reach up to ten, I get a run-time error 13 on the following line `If CBool(Len(vals(a, b + 1))) Then` and I can't figure out how to get rid of it. The code still pastes all the data as it is supposed to do, despite the error message

Comment: I'll add the modified code to an edit in my original question due to character limitations in the comments section

Comment: I found the problem and solved it.  Cells A198:B200 had errors pasted into them by a different macro, and that's what caused the run-time error 13.  Your code worked great all along.  Thank you.